# How to pass the user id to a custom password hasher in Django?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I have migrated password hashes, that are salted using the user id.

I have a custom hasher that extends PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher. But the parameters of the methods do not include any user info.

```py
class MyHasher(PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher):

    def encrypt(self, password, salt, iters, keylen, digestmod):
```

How do I retrieve the user id inside the encrypt method, so I can correctly verify the incoming password?

Comment: If you are migrating away from your custom format, then all you need to do is verify existing passwords using your custom hash. The password field in the db is of the format `algorithm$salt$hash`, so Django has access to the salt when it verifies the password. Then, Django will use the first entry in your `PASSWORD_HASHERS` setting and rehash the password.

Comment: If you are trying to hash new passwords using your hasher, then that's more complicated and I'm afraid I can't help you with that.

Comment: hi  @Alasdair, i'm migrating passwords from a non-Python system

Comment: OK, so if you store your passwords in the format `algorithm$salt$hash` in the Django user table, then Django will be able to read the salt when you verify the password. I don't understand what your `encrypt` method does or where it is called -- as far as I can see it's not a standard method on password hasher classes.